# Adjusting space around figure with subplots

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, figure, subplot

I'm using Matplotlib and struggling to get exactly the right amount of whitespace around a figure I'm plotting that contains a grid of subplots.

Requirements:  be able to choose the aspect ratio of all the subplots (they're all the same), define exactly how much whitespace there is between the subplots and the top, bottom and left of the (saved) figure edge.  I don't need any extra space on the right.

The code I have so far contains the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=6, nrows=2, sharex=True, 
                         sharey=True, figsize=(16,8))

axes[0,0].plot(x,y)
etc...

plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=1.0, wspace=0.02, bottom=0.17, left=0.075, top=0.18)

plt.savefig('Fig1_matplot.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
```

As it is, if I don't specify `figsize=()` the aspect ratio of the subplots is wrong.  If I do, then the aspect ratio changes whenever I change parameters in `subplots_adjust()`.  Apparently `left cannot be >= right` and `bottom cannot be >= top`.  If I do define top to be anything other than 0 it completely compresses all of the subplots down to a line at the bottom of the figure.

If I specify `bbox_inches='tight'` then it cuts off my defined whitespace at the bottom and left, but if I don't specify it then I'm left with excess whitespace on the right since I can't get rid of it (right would be <= left).

I'm a bit stuck, any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

When using `subplots_adjust`, the values of `left`, `right`, `bottom` and `top` are to be provided as fractions of the figure width and height. In additions, all values are measured from the left and bottom edges of the figure. This is why `right` and `top` can't be lower than `left` and `bottom`. A typical set-up is:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.1, right=0.9, bottom=0.1, top=0.9)
```

On the other hand, if you want to provide white space as absolute values in inches, you will have to divide by the figure width and height. For instance in your case, a 1 inch margin around all edges can be achieved with:

```
plt.subplots_adjust(left=1/16.0, right=1-1/16.0, bottom=1/8.0, top=1-1/8.0)
```

For more versatility I usually parametrize the width and height of the figure as:

```
figw, figh = 16.0, 8.0
fig, axes = plt.subplots(ncols=6, nrows=2, sharex=True, sharey=True,
                         figsize=(figw, figh))
plt.subplots_adjust(left=1/figw, right=1-1/figw, bottom=1/figh, top=1-1/figh)
```

The `hspace` and `wspace` are counted as fractions of one panel's axes width and height, so that their absolute value depends on the figure dimensions,  the outer margins and the number of subplots, which will require a tiny bit more math for fine-tuning.

Comment: Nice answer. I find that it's difficult to get a general solution. I place the legend on top of the axes and that often requires adjustment. So I write a convenience function that takes arguments `adjust` and `legend_loc` and I pass `adjust={'left': 0.125, 'bottom': 0.1, 'right': 0.9, 'top': 0.9}` (the typical defaults) and, say, `legend_loc=(1.0, 1.3)`. Inside the convenience function I have `plt.subplots_adjust(left=adjust['left'], right=adjust['right'], bottom=adjust['bottom'], top=adjust['top'])` right before `plt.savefig` and `ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=legend_loc)`, for a single axis `ax`.